# WordPress: Add custom style to Gutenberg group block

Tags: javascript, wordpress, wordpress-gutenberg

I want to add some custom styles to the Gutenberg group block.
Unfortunately the normal way doesn't work.

Here's my code for that (works for heading and other blocks):

```
wp.blocks.registerBlockStyle( 'core/group', {
    name: 'container',
    label: 'Container',
} );
```

Is there no option to add custom styles to this block?
I saw that you can add custom colors and custom styles in the admin. So I don't understand why this wouldn't be possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't remember why my code didn't work.
But now it does. Here's the full working code:

```
wp.domReady( () => {

    wp.blocks.registerBlockStyle(
        'core/group',
        [
            {
                name: 'container',
                label: 'Container',
            }
        ]
    );

} );
```

I guess the code was already correct and I haven't included it in the right way.